# Proper title case in ICU [Does ICU have a list of non-capitalized words?]

Tags: string, icu, capitalization, title-case

Is it possible to obtain proper capitalization for e.g. English text using ICU4C **but without** building any custom set of non-capitalized words? Say, given *`pining for the fjords`* I'd like to obtain *`Pining for the Fjords`*.

With `ucasemap_utf8ToTitle()` and `UnicodeString::toTitle` I get *`Pining For The Fjords`*, no matter which `BreakIterator` or locale I use.

Comment: This is too language dependent (you need a list of stop words, such as articles and propositions) to generalize. Also, it might be context dependent: "I Have Seen the Departed on Television". Finally, it's a matter of preference which words to capitalize and which not.

Comment: I have the same impression.

Comment: @Jongware, I have decided to iterate each word using ICU's **BreakIterator** and compare to my own list of stop words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Jongware should get the credit for explaining this so well. Your question might be  - does ICU have a list of non-capitalized words?

But the short answer for ICU is:  No.

CLDR (from whence ICU gets its data) used to have "Stop words" for search purposes, but they were not well maintained and removed: http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/5204

Comment: Hello Steven, your post is a few years old now and I just ran a test with the latest (ICU 68.1) and 'stop words' are not handled by toTitle. I'm wondering if there are any C/C++ overrides or demo code available using stop words. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Caroline. I don't think there's any change in the situation, as noted, these were not maintained.  If you have a source for maintained stop words and their usefulness, it could be revisitted.